# Fluid layout resize glitch using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

I'm working on a very simple Bootstrap layout. Everything's the way I want, except when I resize the window, sometimes the side bar (Red box) goes bellow the content area (Blue box).

It's a really simple code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid on4-topbar">
        <div class="span12">
            Top bar
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span10 on4-content">
            Content area
        </div>
        <div class="span2 on4-tabs">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                Tab 1
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                Tab 2
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                Tab 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try it using JSFiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/KfqmZ/1/

Here are a couple screenshots detailing the problem. The first one is the expected when resizing, but sometimes, the glitch on scr2 occurs. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOQ4Q.jpg

Does anyone know why this happen and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? A row-fluid should not contain text. Nested row-fluids should contain span* elements. http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem

Comment: Here are the screenshots: http://imgur.com/a/E4c04 Please, note that if you remove the `row-fluid` elements from the `span2` div, the problem persists. So, I don't believe this is the cause.

Comment: I'm using this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KfqmZ/2/. I'm unable to reproduce the problem. I've tested Google Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Martin are you dragging the jsFiddle center column to see the resize in action? Here, using your version after some resizing: http://imgur.com/7QMQn05

Comment: Yes, i've resized it forward and backwards several times without that result. :-/ Can you reproduce the error in another browser?

Comment: @Martin it is indeed a browser problem. I'm using Chrome dev, and it doesn't occur on FF and Safari. I'll try it on with Chrome Stable.